# AppEngine local unit testing guide for Python 2.7 Runtime

Tags: google-app-engine

We're trying to unit test our GAE app locally (models and handlers). The official website/documentation offers very little in term of details or testing patterns. As suggested by that page, we're using `unittest` and `testbed` but that's as far as it goes. Googling brings mostly outdated results from 08-10 when testbed wasn't out yet. We're looking for a thorough guide, patterns, etc. for local unit testing. We've yet to find one, as said above, that is recent or relevant. TIA.

Comment: So, what's real question here? Any concrete trouble/error that you cannot solve. Are you familiar with unittest at all? If not, that's probably a good place to start.